# custom function to filter a pandas dataframe that updates a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Timestamp  RRinterval  Sickness
0       300.080       0.545         0
1       300.625       0.545         0
2       301.005       0.380         0
3       301.575       0.570         0
4       302.150       0.575         0
5       302.500       0.350         0
6       303.070       0.570         0
7       303.450       0.380         0
8       304.020       0.570         0
9       304.405       0.385         0
10      304.805       0.400         0
11      305.505       0.700         0
12      305.705       0.200         0
13      306.440       0.735         0
14      306.630       0.190         0
15      307.010       0.380         0
16      307.390       0.380         0
```

I want to get all markers that select a 12 second period of time so `(row[Timestamp] - prev_marker) % 12 == 0`. This is what I have done so far:

```
tmin = dataset["Timestamp"].iloc[0]
hrs_markers = dataset[ (np.round( (dataset["Timestamp"] - tmin)  % 12 ) == 0)  ].index.tolist()
```

The problem with this code is that `tmin` is not updated when a marker is found. Is it possible to use a function that filter and updates `tmin` when is needed?

Comment: What is your expected output given the input data?

Comment: As I've wrote I want an index list filled with dataframe index for what the condition is verified. The only problem is with the filter because it only relates to the first timestamp and do not updates when a marker is found.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that will face my same problem here a workaround:

```
def filter(values, some_data):
  result = []
  for v in values:
    if some_condition:
      result.append(True)
      # do something with some_data
    else:
      result.append(False)
  return pandas.Series(result)

# in your main code
some_data = ...
vals = dataframe["SomeColumn"].tolist()
bool_serie = filter(vals, parameter)
# here you can filter directly on the whole dataframe
# I've posted the solution in this manner so you can
# easily apply some more complex filter on a pandas.Series
filtered_indexes = dataframe["SomeColumn"][bool_serie].index.tolist()
```

Probabily this solution could be improved, but I think it can give some ideas.